# Upgrading to react-native-paper 5.2 changed @react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-native-paper

[Material-Bottom-Tabs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator) active icon with react-native-paper version 4.9.2 looks like

[image]

[Material-Bottom-Tabs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator) active icon with react-native-paper version 5.2.0 looks like

[image]

I tried searching for something like shadow, background, highlight etc. without success.

When I sourrund my app with the following code the thing behind the icon indeed disappears.

```
const theme = {
  colors: {
  },
};
...
<PaperProvider theme={theme}>
  <MyApp>
</PaperProvider>
```

The documentation of `@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs` doesn't say anything about that. I don't understand why I should have to change anything here. I have not really used `react-native-paper` for anything. For me, it is an optional dependency that improves `@react-navigation`. I understand that I could use it for themes and might decide to so in the future, but why do I need to change anything after upgrading?

[This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815367/react-native-paper-bottomnavigation) is almost a duplicate of mine, however, my issue came with upgrading to `react-native-paper` 5.2.